# Setting the default date on jquery datepicker without populating the underlying input field

Tags: javascript, jquery, datepicker

If I do:

```
$datePicker.datepicker('setDate', null);
```

the underlying input field does not get set to any specific date, but the datepicker widget selects the current date automatically.

[jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/tXyLn/38/)

If I try:

```
$datePicker.datepicker('setDate', "01-01-2014");
```

it will populate the date field.  The same goes for setting defaultDate on the datepicker options.

[jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/tXyLn/40/)

Is there any way to set the widget to a date without having the field populated?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I updated your [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/tXyLn/42/) to work with a textbox rather than a div.
As per [jqueryui documentation](http://api.jqueryui.com/datepicker/#option-defaultDate):

> defaultDateType: Date or Number or String
>   Default: null
>   Set the date to highlight on first opening if the field is blank.

Which means:

```
$('#date').datepicker({ defaultDate: '01/01/2015' });
```

Comment: Yes I have tried this, and it works, but I'm using an inline datepicker so it needs to work with a div.  Is it not possible to do this with a div?

Comment: The documentation doesn't say explicitly, but in my experience: No, it's not possible. How would you distinguish visually between a pre-selected date and one that is actually selected?

Comment: Well isn't that the default behaviour if you use a div and have no defaultDate selected, and let setDate = null?  It selects today's date on the datepicker but doesn't set the val() of the datepicker.  Unless that in itself is a bug.

Comment: It then simply highlights today's date, but it always does that, regardless of the default.

Comment: So should my question then be how to highlight a date without setting it on the datepicker?